# Never given option to install Ubuntu anywhere other than on the USB

Tags: dual-boot, usb, uefi, dell

I'm trying to install Ubuntu (16.04.1) alongside Windows 10 on a Dell XPS 15.

Some firmware specifics:

- Secure boot is off
- Fast boot is set to "thorough" (off)
- Legacy boot is off

Through some experimentation using [Rufus](https://rufus.akeo.ie/), I've managed to create a bootable Ubuntu USB drive, that's actually visible under the UEFI boot options at start up. First hurdle over!

When I boot from the device I'm given the option of installing or trying Ubuntu ([from a screen identical to this](https://i.stack.imgur.com/raY0m.jpg)), so I select to install.

If I start following the installation steps through, after choosing a network connection I'm then told there's not enough space on the device to install, quoting the amount of free space on the USB device.

There's no other options at any stage to change where I want to install to. There's definintely 120GB of unallocated space on my SSD I've freed up specifically for it. It's like it just doesn't know the SSD is there.

Any ideas?

Comment: If you don't see your hard disk in the installer's partitioning screen, then that suggests that your computer (or possibly the disk, if it's an NVMe or something similar) is new enough that it lacks Ubuntu drivers. You *might* have better luck with Ubuntu 16.10, which has a newer kernel, but I can make no promises of that.

Comment: If when trying to install you get to partitioning, select "Something else". then you will see a screen showing the space on the SSD, if not select it from the dropdown.

Comment: Yes it's NVMe @RodSmith, so that could well be the problem. I'll try with Ubuntu 16.10 this evening - thanks for the suggestion :)

Comment: @C.S.Cameron unfortunately it never gets that far

Comment: "Something else" is at the bottom of the "Installation type" window, which should precede "choosing a network connection".

Comment: I've checked each screen thoroughly, there's no such option @C.S.Cameron :( thank you though. I've come to the conclusion I need to enable AHCI in the bios settings for Ubuntu to see the SSD, however that will require re-installing Windows for it to work alongside it, without having to keep switching between the different settings. So hopefully this weekend I'll have a decent number of hours to create an up to date recovery drive and go through the whole process.

Comment: Have you tried a different installer, perhaps UNetbootin rather than Rufus, their syslinux.cfg files are configured a bit differently.

Comment: Thanks for the suggestion. I'm pretty sure it will just be a case of switching to AHCI, however I will give this a quick go beforehand, in case it saves me the trouble of having to reinstall Windows :)

Comment: Thanks for the suggestions guys. I was able to finally get it working by enabling AHCI mode.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The solution was to enable AHCI mode.

Following [these instructions](http://triplescomputers.com/blog/uncategorized/solution-switch-windows-10-from-raidide-to-ahci-operation/) to first enable safe mode before shutting down and changing the mode, I was able to do it without needing to reinstall/restore Windows 10.

Finally have Ubuntu running alongside Windows 10 :)